# Ember Interpolation in a href tag in handlebars template

Tags: ember.js, string-interpolation, handlebars.js

I am trying to make a simple link to google maps with a dynamic address inserted into the href field. I have tried the code below plus tons of other messing around with no luck. How do you interpolate a dynamic ember string in a handlebars href field?

I am using ember,rails, and handlebars.
I know how to use bindAttr if I had the entire url stored with my model but I only have the address. Putting the google url with every model seemed unnecessary if i could just call it once in the view.

```
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
 <div>
  <p><a {{bindAttr href='http://maps.com/?1=address'}}>{{address}}</a></p>
 </div>

<h1>{{name}}</h1>
<div>
  <p><a href='http://maps.google.com/?q={{address}}'>{{address}}</a></p>
</div>
```

What I used to Fix it

```
App.Location = DS.Model.extend(
  name: DS.attr('string', defaultValue: "")
  address:  DS.attr('string', defaultValue: "")
  fullAddress: (->
    "http://maps.google.com/?q=#{@get('address')}"
  ).property('address')
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this, see [demo](http://jsbin.com/OvobowIH/1/edit).

Basically you could create a [`Mixin`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html) for common properties and then mix it in your models.
For example:

```
App.BaseModel = Ember.Mixin.create({
  base: 'http://maps.google.com/?q=',
  fullAddress: function(){
    return this.get('base') + this.get('address');
  }.property('address')
});

App.MyModel = DS.Model.extend(App.BaseModel, {
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  address: DS.attr('string')
});
```

So you could later use it in you templates like this:

```
{{#each model}}
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
  <div>
    <p><a {{bind-attr href='fullAddress'}}>{{address}}</a></p>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks!! you definitely pointed me in the right direction. THis is my first time using all these technologies together. Rails,Ruby,Ember,Coffeescript, Handlebars so I am still a little confused how to structure everything but I fixed it with the code I added to the question. Thanks again!

Comment: @GarrettBoone I'm glad I could help, feel free to post more question here on SO, I'm sure they get answered successfully :)

Comment: @intuitivepixel that jsbin isn't working. (doesn't render the template)